# Problem request between MySql And MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, subquery, sql-order-by

I need you help to resolve a problem..

Before, my website used MySql 5.5
Now, it seems to use MariaDB 10.0

I found no difference but...

This request (I have simplified the request for a better understanding)

```
select * from ( select * from MYTABLE ) tmpTable ORDER BY tmpTable.id DESC
```

This request WORKS on Mysql and MariaDB

BUT...

```
select * from ( select * from MYTABLE ORDER BY tmpTable.id DESC) tmpTable
```

I think if my order by is inside my seconde select, he is not concidered

This request DOESN'T WORK ! Result is good, but ORDER BY doesn't work ... It's order by ASCENDING and not DESCENDING like I specified in my second select ...

Someone understand why ? Is it a difference between mysql and Maria DB?

Thanks a lot !
Have a good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, rows of a table have no pre-defined order. You need `order by` to sort a record set.

What happens with the second query is that the subquery creates a derived table that is then used in the outer query. The fact that you order the rows in the subquery does not make a difference: from the perspective of the outer query, rows of the derived table have no inherent ordering.

In other words there is no guarantee that the inner sort propagates to the outer scope. If you want the resultset to be consistently sorted, use `order by` in the outer scope.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! but You know why it works on Mysql and no with MariaDB ? Is it a luck that it works on Mysql? Mysql handles this problem and mariaDb does not ? I need to know if I need to extern ORDER BY inside first request, or If It's better to change MariaDB TO MYSQL

Comment: @MathAng: I don't think this is safe, even in MySQL. Although it might work today, it could break anytime in the future.